# Do I need Azure API Management service to restrict web api endpoints inside an Azure virtual network?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-api-management

My plan is to have an Azure function using a timer trigger call a REST web API endpoint that is not accessible to the internet - only inside an Azure virtual network.

Is it enough to have both the Azure function and web API inside an Azure virtual network or do I have to use the Azure API Management service in conjunction with the virtual network to restrict the web API endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using dedicated plan, you can [deploy the functions runtime as a site extension](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Deploying-the-Functions-runtime-as-a-private-site-extension) with a modified web.config with the ip whitelist you need.

If you are using consumption plan you cannot do that. You need something (like API Management) to front Azure Function and do the filtering.

Another option would be to use Function authorization. Non authorized calls to the function are not billed.